# Prins reaction mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am trying to figure out the product for the following reaction:
[image]

Its a Prins Reaction. My proposed mechanism for it is:

[image]

In my second step, that particular carbocation is formed since $\ce{Ph}$ is an electron-withdrawing group.

Mechanism looks neat enough, but the reaction given in [Wiley's Solomon and Fryhle (Page 379)](https://www.amazon.in/Solomons-Organic-Chemistry-Advanced-2017-18/dp/B072HRZ3JV?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=3f7ebfff-3883-41d6-a54f-e3a5b1baf88f) is:

[image]

I'd like to know why my mechanism is "wrong"? I think there's problem in the carbocation generation step but isn't the carbocation that I have formed more stable?

Comment: The carbocation will definitely form at the benzyl carbon. The fact that the benzene ring can stabilize the cation through resonance outweighs the disadvantages of negative inductive effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your generation of electrophile is correct the subsequent primary carbocation formation by the attack of electrophile is incorrect.

> In my second step, that particular carbocation is formed since $\ce{Ph}$ is an electron-withdrawing group.

The benzene ring  stabilizes the carbocation through mesomeric effect.

The electrophile will attack at $\alpha$ position rather than $\beta$

> [image]